# Scaling view & image with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift, image, crop

I am looking for a solution to save a UIView (with its subviews) saved as an image to the devices photo library. I would like the size of the output image to be 1024 x 1024. The UIView will always be a square thus subviews will fit inside the square. The resulted saved output must satisfy these needs.

Here is what I have:

```
let outputSize = CGSize(width: 1024.0, height: 1024.0)

func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outputSize, view.opaque, 0.0)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let outputImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return outputImage
}
```

The view I am passing into the parameter above is the square view. The screenshot below is the result:

[image: crop scale is off]

In my storyboard, the UIView is square at 280x280 (if that makes a difference.) My desired result is the UIView (and photo inside of it) gets saved the full size of the black frame (which is 1024 sq). Thanks for the help.

**edit**

Here is an updated version:
While it satisfies the needs of outputting the view at 1024 square, the quality is not very desirable. Would like to use the CGBitmapContextCreate & CGContextDrawImage method discussed here: http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

```
func stackOverflow() -> UIImage{

    let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 1.0

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0), !hasAlpha, scale)

    mainView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0)), afterScreenUpdates:  false)

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return scaledImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.URL.absoluteString!)

let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(image.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5))
let hasAlpha = false
let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

As shown [here](http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/).

Comment: Check my edit above. I had to tweak a few things around for it to work with my needs. While it does export the final image to 1024 square, the image quality is not very desirable. That NSHipster link you provided looks like it has a more robust solution with: CGBitmapContextCreate & CGContextDrawImage - this will allow me to specify quality with CGInterpolationQuality. I'm having a tough time getting that to export the UIView and its subviews, as it's looking for a CGImage argument. Can you provide any tips on how to get this to work for my needs outlined above? Thank you.

Comment: What's actually happening? You're unable to convert the UIImage to CGImage or what? You can do that by `UIImage(name: "Something")?.CGImage` and follow along the rest of the procedure there.

Comment: I got the UIImage casted as CGImage, so that's working fine. The problem is incorporating the square UIView into the method. I believe it needs to be added into CGContextDrawImage or CGBitmapCreateImage, however nothing I tried produced any worthy results.

Comment: func stackoverflow(view: UIView) -> UIImage{

let myView = view
}

Comment: i don't understand what you meant by that comment. The stackOverflow method I have edited above works... I just would like to get the CGBitmapContextCreate & CGContextDrawImage version to work WITH the square view, as that has more grainular control of image quality.

Comment: Yeah that's what i told in my comment. Make that function accept a UIView, and assign your sqaure view to that and wherever it is necessary in that function.